# Perl regex not matcing text

Tags: regex, perl

I am newbie in Perl. I have used regex in Python. I have array `list` where each elem is text.

```
"  Some explanation about some thing
  Root ID    Priority    12313
             Address     mac-address
             Cost       4
             Port        1234
             This is the awesome root
            "
```

Here `Cost` and `Port` may be or may not be present in text. So I have written two regex expressions.

```
foreach $item (@list){
    $item =~ /Cost\s+(?<cost>\d+).*?Port\s+(?<port>\d+)/sg;
    print "cost: $+{cost} port: $+{port}\n";
    $item =~ /Root\s+ID\s+Priority\s+(?<rootPriority>\d+).*?Address\s+(?<rootAddress>\S+).*/sg;
    print "rootPriority: $+{rootPriority} rootAddress: $+{rootAddress} \n";

    print $item;
}
```

Output,

```
cost: 2 port: 4096
rootPriority:  rootAddress:
    Some explanation about some thing
      Root ID    Priority    12313
                 Address     mac-address
                 Cost       2
                 Port        4096
    This is the awesome root
```

I am not able to understand why I can get values of `cost` and `port` but not of `rootPriority` and `rootAddress`. And how to get values of `rootPriority` and `rootAddress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TLP has pointed out, a global match maintains a *state*, and searches for one instance of the pattern at a time, returning *false* when there are no more. In list context that is fine -- all the matches are found and returned at once. But in scalar context, each subsequent *global* pattern match continues from where the previous one left off, and because `Priority` and `Address` appear *before* `cost` and `port` they aren't found.

But you aren't, for example, looking for *"all the instances of `Cost`"* -- you simply want the first (and only) one. So simply remove the `/g` modifiers from the pattern matches.

Please also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare all your variables using `my`, as close as possible to their first point of use.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = (
"  Some explanation about some thing
  Root ID    Priority    12313
             Address     mac-address
             Cost       4
             Port        1234
             This is the awesome root
            ");

for my $item (@list){

    $item =~ /Cost\s+(?<cost>\d+).*?Port\s+(?<port>\d+)/s;
    print "cost: $+{cost} port: $+{port}\n";

    $item =~ /Root\s+ID\s+Priority\s+(?<rootPriority>\d+).*?Address\s+(?<rootAddress>\S+).*/s;
    print "rootPriority: $+{rootPriority} rootAddress: $+{rootAddress} \n";

    print "\n\n";

    print $item;
}
```

**output**

```
cost: 4 port: 1234
rootPriority: 12313 rootAddress: mac-address 


  Some explanation about some thing
  Root ID    Priority    12313
             Address     mac-address
             Cost       4
             Port        1234
             This is the awesome root
```

---

**Update**

I would probably write it more like this. It uses the default loop control variable `$_` which doesn't need to be specified in pattern matches or the `print` statement, and extracts each field one by one using a list assignment.

```
for (@list) {

    my ($cost)         = /Cost\s+(\d+)/;
    my ($port)         = /Port\s+(\d+)/;
    my ($rootPriority) = /Priority\s+(\d+)/;
    my ($rootAddress)  = /Address\s+(\S+)/;

    print "cost: $cost port: $port\n";
    print "rootPriority: $rootPriority rootAddress: $rootAddress\n";
    print "\n\n";

    print;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you perform two regex matches on the same variable, using the `/g` modifier (which you don't even need in this case), the match position is saved, so that you can iterate through the matches when in scalar context. And because the "cost" match comes after the "priority" match, this cannot match.

To make it work, all you need to do is switch places for the regex matches. But you also need to remove the quite redundant `.*` part, or you will have the same problem (because `/s` allows `.` to match newlines).

This code works for me:

```
$item =~ /Root\s+ID\s+Priority\s+(?<rootPriority>\d+).*?Address\s+(?<rootAddress>\S+)/sg;
print "rootPriority: $+{rootPriority} rootAddress: $+{rootAddress} \n";
$item =~ /Cost\s+(?<cost>\d+).*?Port\s+(?<port>\d+)/sg;
print "cost: $+{cost} port: $+{port}\n";
```